# Java SimpleDateFormat parse returning the wrong day

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a string in the format of "Monday, May 15 at 1:00 PM" into a datetime so that i can enter it into a database. However the parse isnt returning the right day when i'm testing this out. Does anyone have any ideas what's happening?

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws ParseException
    {

        String inDateTime = "Monday, May 15 at 1:00 PM";

        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd 'at' hh:mm aa").parse(inDateTime);

        String outDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEE MMMMMM dd hh:mm aa").format( date );

        System.out.println(outDateTime);

    }
}
```

And the output from netbeans

```
[exec:exec]
Friday May 15 01:00 PM
```

Any ideas why Monday is turning into Friday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting the year so `SimpleDateFormat` is using the one from the epoch. May 15 1970  occurred on a Friday.

The day input field is ignored if month and date fields are present so this field can be omitted.

You will need to specify a year where May 15 occurred on a Monday.

Comment: Thank you, I will artificially add in the year to the beginning of the string to make it work, the format i will be receiving it in does not include the year.

Answer (score 0):

your code is equvalent  to

```
String inDateTime = "1970 Monday, May 15 at 1:00 PM";

    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy EEE, MMM dd 'at' hh:mm aa")
                 .parse(inDateTime);

String outDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEE MMMMMM dd hh:mm aa")
                 .format( date );

    System.out.println(outDateTime); //prints Friday May 15 01:00 PM
```

So please add `year`

Comment: Thank you, I will artificially add in the year to the beginning of the string to make it work, the format i will be receiving it in does not include the year.

Comment: Ok.no issues.glad to help.mark it as answer if its helpful.click the tickmark.